# Refresh com angular + IIS

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, rotas

Publiquei uma aplicação angular no IIS e de inicio minha aplicação funciona normalmente, porém ao dar refresh na pagina, recebo um erro de Not Found. Procurei em vários sites na internet e vi que era necessário criar um arquivo WebConfig na mesma pasta aonde estão seus arquivos do angular. Fiz isso, porém mesmo assim continua o mesmo erro.

Aqui está minha WebConfig:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration> 
<system.webServer> 
    <rewrite> 
        <rules> 
            <rule name="TestDrive"> 
                <match url=".*" /> 
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" /> 
                </conditions> 
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./" appendQueryString="true" /> 
            </rule> 
        </rules> 
    </rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

Aqui está o print da configuração da aplicação no IIS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Opções de Pool

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Como está a configuração do pool? é um site ou uma applicação dentro de outro site?

Comment: É um site. E o pool está como 'DefaultAppPool'. De qualquer forma, vou editar minha pergunta colocando um print de como está.

Comment: Então, pelo print ele não é um site, e sim uma aplicação dentro do seu site default, tanto que você deve estar acessando ele por `http://localhost/TestDrive`, enquanto a sua aplicação angular não está reconhecendo esse subdiretorio como sua raíz...

Comment: Entendi! mas como consigo resolver esse problema?

Comment: Aí depende de como será em produção... mas crie um novo site para sua aplicação ou se você não terá mais nenhum simplesmente aponte o caminho do "Default Web Site" para o seu aplicativo: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestDrive"

Comment: Criei um novo Site assim como você pediu, porém, sem a WebConfig da o mesmo erro, ele abre a tela e no refresh é apresentado o erro 404. E com a WebConfig ele nem abre a tela mais...

Comment: Então, acredito que não, pois em rodando na minha maquina sem ser pelo IIS, funciona normalmente.

Comment: Beleza! Só 1 min

Comment: Mude o pool desse site para Não gerenciado e clássico, outra dúvida como está o seu `<base href>`

Comment: Não tenho essa opção! vou colocar na pergunta as opções de Pool que tenho

Comment: Edite o pool TestDrive

Comment: Já esta como TestDrive! Lembrando que se eu tiro a WebConfig, a tela abre normalmente, porem sem o refresh funcionar! e com a WebConfig, a tela nem abre

Comment: talvez te ajude: http://getgoingit.blogspot.com/2018/02/publishing-and-deploying-angular-4.html, tem uns passos a mais do que você fez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive que instalar esse software no servidor:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Apos a instalação, e com a mesma WebConfig descrita na pergunta, o refresh funcionou.